# Ionic build failed

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have been having this problem for a while now and i tried all the solutions on the internet but none of them helped.
I have this error whenever I run : `Ionic run android`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\hamiri\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-
tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
    option to get more log output.
```

When running `gradlew.bat --info build clean`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Script 'D:\HomeTest\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 117

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Unable to determine Android SDK directory.
```

I made sure to verify tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe is there.
Anybody can help me fix this?

Comment: Have you set `ANDROID_HOME` variable in your system path?

Comment: @Hana did you fix this ?

Comment: yes the problem was not really related to the error. I had an image, in the project that has "é" in its name. ANd that was causing the problem